# Comment dire « as well as » en français ?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

Comment est-ce que je peux dire « *as well as* » en français ? Je pense que « aussi bien que » est correct. Est-ce que quelqu'un peut confirmer ?

Le contexte dans lequel j'ai eu besoin de dire « as well as » est :

> Il a tout de suite commencé a construire des tours et des châteaux afin de protéger ses nouveaux territoires contre les menaces extérieures **as well as** les quelques trahisons des gens à l'intérieur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans votre contexte, *ainsi que* semble plus correct. *Aussi bien que* insiste sur adéquation entre les deux proposition : voici un exemple :

> J'aime manger des fruits aussi bien que des légumes.

Ici, on insiste sur le fait que l'on aime manger des **fruits** et des **légumes** de façon équivalente (de la même façon avec *autant que*).

> J'aime manger des fruits ainsi que des légumes.

Ici, on dit juste que l'on aime manger des **fruits** et des **légumes**, sans préciser qu'on aime autant les deux.

En utilisant *plus que* et *moins que* par exemple, on pourrait aussi préciser une préférence.

Comment: C'est parfait ! J'ai compris la différence entre aussi bien que et ainsi que, merci. Donc ma phrase devrait être : "Il a tout de suite commencé a construire des tours et des châteaux afin de protéger ses nouvelles territoires contre des ménaces extérieurs ainsi que des quelques trahisons des gens à l'intérieur".

Comment: Hum non, elle devrait être "Il a tout de suite commencé **à** construire des tours et des châteaux afin de protéger ses **nouveaux** territoires contre **les** menaces **extérieures** ainsi que **les** quelques trahisons des gens à l'intérieur".

Comment: Merci - je suis désolé, je suis en train d'apprendre le Français donc je fais beaucoup des erreurs, comme "commence a" ou "nouvelles territories". Mais j'ai un question : pourquoi as-tu dit "les menaces extérieures" et "les quelques trahisons des gens" ? Ce sont choses indéfinis je pense donc pourquoi on doit utiliser les articles définis?

Comment: C'est parfaitement compréhensible. J'ajouterais juste que "gens à l’intérieur" peut sembler maladroit, il faudrait peut-être mieux utiliser le terme exact qui me semble être dans votre cas *habitant* (cependant je n'en suis pas sûr, n'ayant pas le contexte de votre phrase).

Comment: Ok, je vais vous donner le contexte : j'etais en train d'essayer d'expliquer à un ami français la différence entre London et City of London quand j'ai dit la phrase au-dessus. Donc "les gens à l'intérieur" sont les habitants qui étaient dans la ville de Londres. La protéction construit par William (je pense que vous disez Guillaume en Français) servait pour le défendre contre le extérieur (vikings) et aussi pour le protéger contre les habitants qui habitaient dans la ville de Londres.

Comment: *Les habitants* convient donc mieux, cependant, *les gens à l’intérieur* est parfaitement compréhensible. A propos de votre question sur défini/indéfini, les menaces et les trahisons sont bien définies. Vous ne parlez pas de n'importe quelles menaces mais de celles menaçant Londres. Vous pouvez aussi utiliser "protéger ses nouveaux territoires **des** menaces extérieures" sans utiliser "contre" : ici **des** est article défini contracté (*de les* => *des*) et non article indéfini.

Answer (score 3):

Le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle mais je peux quand même contribuer avec le peu de chose que je connais…

Littéralement, « as well as »  est la formule « as… as… » qui exprime un parallélisme, augmentée de « well », dans le sens de « bien » donc l’équivalent le plus proche en français serait « **aussi bien que** » qui peut se réduire dans l'approche la plus  simpliste à l'usage de « **et** »…

Globalement, « as well as », en anglais, exprime un parallélisme dans la phrase mais ce sont les nuances qui diffèrent :

- Exemple 1

  > C#, **as well as** java, is considered as an Object Oriented Programming language…

  donne

  > C#, **de même que** java, est considéré comme un langage de programmation orientée objet…

  Ici, « as well as » peut être vu comme un « et », dans le sens de « ainsi que » ou « de plus ».
- Exemple 2

  > Cats, dogs, birds **as well as** mice were her friends.

  donne

  > Chats, chiens, oiseaux, **ainsi que** souris étaient ses amis.

  Ici « as well as » exprime le sens de « et » mais avec une nuance faible pour  « les souris » (c'est comme si on dit « sans oublier les souris »).
- Exemple 3

  > That contributed to the increase in the inflation rate at the beginnig of the year, **as well as** to its decrease at the end of the year.

  donne

  > Cela a contribué à la hausse du taux d'inflation au début de l'année **de la même façon** qu'il a contribué à réduire l'inflation à la fin de l'année.

  Ici on mentionne deux faits qui vont en parallèle mais dans deux sens totalement opposés : le fait dont il est question a contribué **par la même intensité** à accroitre puis à réduire le taux d'inflation
- Exemple 4

  > I can rectify my mistakes **as well as** I can make them.

  donne

  > Je peux corriger mes erreurs **de la même façon** que je peux en commettre (quelques unes…).

  Il est clair ici que les deux effets sont en exclusion mutuelle et ne peuvent pas se faire simultanément : « as well as » n'exprime pas ici un « et » mais  il est plutôt question d'insister sur le fait que les deux actions « ont le même degré d'intensité ».
- Pour plus de clarté, j'ajoute un exemple avec « aussi bien que » tiré de la page [*aussi bien*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aussi_bien) du Wiktionnaire.

  > Le baillistre, **aussi bien que** le gardien, n'administre pas pour le compte du mineur, mais pour son propre compte : il a la jouissance du fief dont il fait les fruits siens, civils ou naturels. — (Gabriel Lepointe, *La Famille dans l'Ancien droit*, Montchrestien, 1947 ; 5<sup>e</sup> édition, 1956, p. 228)

Puisque [servabat](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3354/servabat) a déjà répondu sur cette question convenablement, je vais seulement donner une version alternative de l'expression cherchée, avec « de même que » :

> Il a tout de suite commencé a construire des tours et des châteaux afin de protéger ses nouveaux territoires contre les menaces extérieures **de même que** les quelques trahisons des gens, à l'intérieur.